# Cannot select/edit text in UITextView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, masonry

I have setup my UIScrollView with subviews like so using Masonry:

```
- (void)setupViews {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor Background];
    self.scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
    }];
    self.contentView = [UIView new];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView);
        make.left.and.right.equalTo(self.view);
    }];
    self.imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.imageButton sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.card.cardImageURL] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.imageButton.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageButton];
    [self.imageButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.and.right.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.height.equalTo(self.imageButton.mas_width).multipliedBy(3/4.0);
    }];
    self.textField = [UITextField new];
    self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textField.font = kFontRegular(14);
    self.textField.text = self.card.cardTitle;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
    [self.textField mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(8);
        make.top.equalTo(self.imageButton.mas_bottom).with.offset(8);
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(-8);
        make.height.equalTo(@(45));
    }];
}
```

but it will not let me interact with the UITextField. what element here is preventing user interaction?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to set enable, editable, ...?

Comment: yes, a UITextField should be editable by default anyway

Comment: Can you try to use background for sure the constraint is ok?

Comment: I afraid about the frame of UITextField. Not sure. I don't know the reason like you.

Comment: those lines weren't necessary - i have edited my code above. it is still non-interactable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contentView's height will be zero. So it will never get some touch events. You should not use this constraint:

```
make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView);
```

It will not get a correct value. Try to set top and height constraints for your contentView.

```
make.top.equalTo(@0);
make.height.equalTo(@700);
```